# Сконкатенировать результат Promise.all?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

По итогам двух запросов ( а их может быть даже больше ), требуется возвращаемые массивы из ответа конкатенировать в один массив:

```js
const getQuriesResult = async () => {
   const resultArray = [];
   
   Promise.all([
      await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'),
      await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
   ]).then( results => {

      results.map( ( item, i, arr ) => {
         
         // тут нужна конкатенация всех массивов из всех запросов в один...
         
         console.log(arr[i].data);
         // resultArray.concat(arr[i].data);
      } )
   });
};

getQuriesResult();
```

[Песочница](https://codepen.io/overusdev/pen/bGqrbZQ?editors=1010)

Буду очень благодарен за решение.

Comment: а чем не устраивает вариант приведенный в вопросе?

Comment: Но ведь он же не работает

Comment: а, точно, `concat` возвращает новый массив, поэтому результат выполнения нужно сохранять `resultArray = resultArray.concat(arr[i].data)`

Comment: так же, обрати внимание, что в твоем случае, тебе не нужен `Promise.all`, так как ты последовательно дожидаешься результатов запросов и можешь просто пушить их в результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const getQuriesResult = async () => {
   const res = await Promise.all([
      await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'),
      await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
   ]);
   let results = [];
   res.forEach((obj) => {
      results = [...results, ...obj.data];
      }
   );
   return results
};

getQuriesResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

Для объединения массивов можно применить метод [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Данный метод может принимать несколько массивов для объединения.

Таким образом код объединения может выглядеть так:

```
.then( results => {
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(...results);
})
```

Так как [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) возвращает новый массив, результат выполнения нужно сохранять.

Также стоит обратить внимание, на не совсем верное использование `await` в коде в вопросе.

```
Promise.all([
  await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'),
  await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
])
```

Данная запись не имеет особого смысла, так как [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) используется для ожидания всех `Promise`, однако в данном случае, ему в параметры передаются сами значения, а не `Promise`.

Таким образом код можно заменить следующим:

```
const results = await Promise.all([
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'),
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
]);
```

Далее уже работать с переменной `results`.

Если перед объединением результатов необходимо их предварительно обработать, например получить определенное свойство, можно воспользоваться методом [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Итоговый код может стать таким:

```js
(async() => {
  const getQuriesResult = async() => {
    const resultArray = [];

    const results = await Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'),
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    ]);

    return resultArray.concat(...results.map(item => item.data));
  };

  console.log(
    await getQuriesResult()
  );
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```